# Check if any string in a list of strings is in a pandas row and return bool result

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to return bool column based on a condition:

- column with sentences
- list = ['foo', 'box']
- if any from *list* in row -> return True, else return False

My code does not work and I can't find the mistake:

```
clean_df['to_process'] = clean_df['sentence'].apply(
    lambda x: True if any(st in x for st in ['foo','box']) else False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with join list for regex `OR`:

```
L = ['foo','box']
clean_df['to_process'] = clean_df['sentence'].str.contains('|'.join(L))
```